# adding a value to a MYSQL SELECT statement, depending on the value of calculated field

Tags: mysql

I have the following query

```
SELECT `username`, TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, STR_TO_DATE(enrolmentDate, '%d-%m-%Y'), now()) AS day 
FROM `users`
```

This results in 2 columns, with a numeric value in the 'day' column.

Is there a way to add a 3rd column whose value is either 1 or 0, depending on the number in the 'day' column? I'd like a 1 in the new column if the value in 'day' is more than 700 and a 0 if it isn't.

Ideal result:

username    |  days   |  core

username 1 |  100    |   0

username 2 |  800    |   1

I could perform this check in PHP after the data is retrieved, but I think MYSQL is probably the more efficient way to go if it can do it?

Thanks for any tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using subquery as follows,

```
SELECT z.*, IF(z.day > 700, 1, 0) AS core
FROM
  (
    SELECT `username`,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, STR_TO_DATE(enrolmentDate, '%d-%m-%Y'), now()) AS day 
    FROM `users`
  ) z
```

Comment: This works like an absolute charm. Thanks for your time and effort. I hadn't looked outside the box enough. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can reference the result of a calculated column in the same SELECT statement. Try this instead: let day := `TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, STR_TO_DATE(enrolmentDate, '%d-%m-%Y'), now())`. Then your third column is 1 / 2 * SIGN(day - 700) + 1 / 2 (this maps to 0 if day < 700, 1 if day > 700, and 1 / 2 if day == 700.